Azure Pipelines Trying to Find Correct Environment Value repository checkout
what pipeline variable is this path?
i'm hunting for the environment variable for this value
i've tried $(Build.SourcesDirectory) and $(Agent.BuildDirectory)
these all come up in C drive, is there a source of output for all the pipeline environment variables per run?
resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: self
    type: git
    ref: refs/heads/master
...
        steps:
        - checkout: self
...
        - task: PowerShell@2
          displayName: Display Build Dir
          inputs:
            targetType: 'inline'
            script: 'Write-Host "Build Directory Location: `"$(Agent.BuildDirectory)`""' 

        - task: NuGetCommand@2
          displayName: NuGet restore
          inputs:
            solution: '$(BuildParameters.solution)'
            selectOrConfig: config
            nugetConfigPath: '$(Agent.BuildDirectory)/src/tree0/nuget.config'



Refer to the documentation. The default checkout location is $(Pipeline.Workspace). https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/steps-checkout?view=azure-pipelines

@DanielMann $(Pipeline.Workspace) still pulls C drive

actually, after outputting all env variables to the job, all of them point to C drive. I have no clue why checkout uses D drive but environment uses C

@ChrisHayes, Post the completed YAML and output logs of your pipeline, so that we can check more details of the configurations in your pipeline.

@BrightRan-MSFT no-can-do, those files contain proprietary information

idk why but using NugetCommand@2 with 'restore' command on this windows agent uses back slashes \. There was no error informing me of this. I changed the slashes and it started working.
despite the docs stating elsewise, see: slash documentation pipeline and seeing no contrary info in the task documentation: path variable doc in NugetCommand@2 i was left to trial and error (not really, a coworker suggested it but I dismissed the advice after reading the docs, silly me)
the code WAS in C drive despite the output of the checkout task stating elsewise. How did I find this out. I ran a recursive directory output that showed all the files.

If the solution you shared in this answer works for you, maybe, you can accept it. It could be also helpful for other people who are looking for a solution of the similar issues.

The value of predefined variable "Agent.BuildDirectory" is the local path on the agent where a pipeline is working in. The predefined variable "Pipeline.Workspace" also has the same value.
The "Build.SourcesDirectory" is a Azure Pipelines predefined variable, and its value is the local path on the agent where your source code files are downloaded. The predefined variables "Build.Repository.LocalPath" and "System.DefaultWorkingDirectory" also have the same value.
The "Build.SourcesDirectory" is a subdirectory under "Agent.BuildDirectory".
For example:
There is an Windows agent named Win11-01, and its installation directory on the agent machine is "E:\VstsAgents\Win11_01", when running jobs using this agent, you might need to use the following predefined variables:

Agent.WorkFolder: The working directory for this agent ( E:\VstsAgents\Win11_01\_work). It contains the working directories for all jobs run on this agent.

Agent.BuildDirectory: The working directory for each pipeline which has jobs run on this agent ( E:\VstsAgents\Win11_01\_work\<number>). The <number> folder will be named as 1, 2, 3, 4, etc.. which are automatically generated for each pipeline by sequential. For example, E:\VstsAgents\Win11_01\_work\1.

Pipeline.Workspace: Same as Agent.BuildDirectory.

Build.SourcesDirectory: The directory where the source code files are downloaded into (E:\VstsAgents\Win11_01\_work\<number>\s). This is the default directory that the checkout task will put the downloaded files into. On the checkout task, you can use the path option to specify a different directory.

When you set the job to check out just one repository, the content of the repository will be directly put into this directory.
When you set the job to check out multiple repositories, the content of each repository will be put into the directory "E:\VstsAgents\Win11_01\_work\<number>\s\<repository-name>".


Build.Repository.LocalPath and System.DefaultWorkingDirectory: Same as Build.SourcesDirectory.


For more predefined variables in Azure Pipelines, you can see the documentation "Use predefined variables".

